# Dom-Repeat Render: What is it actually do? Proper way to tell dom-repeat re-render its item?

Tags: polymer

I was fighting with a nested dom-repeat for the last 2 days.
I somewhat now know how to re-render when sub-properties changed.

But still don't understand the purpose of the render function.
I changed the data binded to a dom-repeat, and call the render, but nothing happens.

```
_renderDREmployees: function() {
  this.employees[0].name="RENDERED"
  // Why this doesn't work ?
  this.$.drEmployees.render()
},
```

See here
http://plnkr.co/edit/Y0P5vNxg46t5fX7gJFxU?p=preview

Could somebody explain to me please?

If you could take a look of my example, to see if I do it the right away.
What could be other ways/proper way to re-render item inside a dom-repeat when the data that binded to it was changed outside.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In order to mutate object properties in Polymer, you must use the object mutation methods in order for this changes to propagate inside your element.

Hence,

```
this.employees[0].name="RENDERED"
```

should be

```
this.set('employees.#0.name', 'RENDERED')
```

> `render` only picks up observable changes such as those made with Polymer's array mutation methods.

Answer (score 0):

Here is example where it works(I mean on name="RENDERED"): [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/pmozne9ZlVuLNXdTYM2J?p=preview)

Right way to do it is:

```
this.set('employees.0.name', "RENDERED set");
```

Docs [Polymer array-binding](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding#array-binding)

Comment: Thank. Yes I do know how to do like you suggested (if you look at other functions in my code). My question is: "What is the real purpose of the render function? what is it used for?"